# Cyclic coordinate Search Optimization, updating new optimum using for loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, optimization, scipy-optimize

In cyclic coordinate search, we look for an optimum inline with each one of the coordinate axes.
I have defined the variable x_new as an updated variable for the start point. Inside the loop, the objective function is minimized first in the x1 direction and then the x2 direction.

I am having trouble actually updating x_new. It will not update as currently coded and when printed is output as [0, 0].

```
import scipy.optimize as opt                                            
import numpy as np                                                      
# Objective Function                                                    
# f(x1,x2) = (x2-x1**2)**4 + (3-x1)**2                                  
# x = [0, 0]                                                            
                                                                        
# Initialize                                                            
x0 = np.array([0, 0])                                                   
iter = 0                                                                
epsilon = 0.0001                                                        
x_new = x0                                                              
                                                                        
for i in range(len(x0)):                                                
    if i == 0:                                                          
        def obj_func(x):                                                
            return (x_new[1] - x ** 2) ** 4 + (3 - x) ** 2              
        x_new[0] = opt.minimize_scalar(obj_func).x                                                                                    
    else:                                                               
        def obj_func(x):                                                
            return (x - x_new[0]**2) ** 4 + (3 - x_new[0]) ** 2         
        x_new[1] = opt.minimize_scalar(obj_func).x                                                                                   
    iter += 1                                                           
                                                                        
                                                                        
print(x_new)                                                            
print(iter)
```

This is the output of this code

How can I get x_new to update or am I approaching this all wrong?

Comment: Hi, sorry if this is unrelated, but do you have a literature reference where I can see how we choose the coordinate in a 'cyclic' manner?

Comment: Sorry, I no longer have a reference for this method, but I was able to figure out the issue.

Comment: What is this search method does is that it minimizes one variable (Coordinate direction) of the objective function. It then minimizes the objective function using the second variable. This cycle repeats until a global or local minima of the objective function is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I didn't define the numpy arrays as floats so it wouldn't update the original assignment of x_new

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
import numpy as np

# Objective Function
# f(x1,x2) = (x2-x1**2)**4 + (3-x1)**2
# x = [0, 0]

x_new = np.array([0.0, 0.0])
x0 = np.array([0.0, 0.0])
x_hist = np.array([0.0, 0.0])
f = np.array([9])
iter = 0
while iter < 12:
    for i in range(len(x0)):
        if i == 0:
            def obj_func(x):
                return (x_new[1] - x ** 2) ** 4 + (3 - x) ** 2
            x_new[0] = opt.minimize_scalar(obj_func).x
            f = np.append(f, obj_func(x_new[0]))
            x_hist = np.append(x_hist, x_new[0])
            iter += 1
        else:
            def obj_func(x):
                return (x - x_new[0] ** 2) ** 4 + (3 - x_new[0]) ** 2
            x_new[1] = opt.minimize_scalar(obj_func).x
            x_hist = np.append(x_hist, x_new[1])
            f = np.append(f, obj_func(x_new[1]))
            iter += 1

print('The optimum value found after', iter, 'iterations is f* = ',
      round((x_new[1] - x_new[0] ** 2) ** 4 + (3 - x_new[0]) ** 2, 5),
      '\nThe optimizers were x* = ', x_new, '\nThe minimum was found using',
      'Cyclic Coordinate Search w/o acceleration')
```